# Mapreduce Program to count total number of Cars in a Video

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hipi

I am very much new to hadoop mapreduce. I have found and implemented the solution of cars count using Opencv but i am really not finding a way in Hadoop Mapreduce way of coding ?
Give me some solution or suggestion about writing image processing code using hadoop mapreduce?

P.S : I am using Java Language with operating system Ubuntu

Comment: I have never used it, but it seems like it might be useful for you : http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/

Comment: Thanks for response i 'll obviously have a look at this , Is there any proper articles or algorithm to solve this problem ?

Comment: is there any body?

Comment: Kindly write it in English ?